# Create a static timer in program.cs with form1 in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

We want to create a timer in the `static void Main()` method, and this timer will have event handler `aTimer_Elapsed`. In the event handler will have this statement `Number = Number+1;` every time the event handler is fired, this Number will be added 1 in the static void Main() program.

There is a `form1`, it will have a button to retrieve the Number's value from `static void Main()` program then display at `textbox1.Text`.

Base on my understanding, this should work, however when start debugging the program, by pressing the button on the `form1`, there is no value update on the `textbox1.Text` (* it only has the default value "0").

Then only we realize that the timer's event handler is not fired. This is where I don't understand, perhaps with your expertise could share with us, how would this happen and how to fix this..

Below is the program.cs code.

```
    static class Program
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The main entry point for the application.
            /// </summary>
            public static int Number = 0;
            static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
            /// 
            [STAThread]
            static void Main()
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());

                aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
                aTimer.Elapsed += aTimer_Elapsed;
                aTimer.Interval = 1000;
                aTimer.Enabled = true;
            }

            static void aTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
                //throw new NotImplementedException();
                Number = Number + 1;

            }
        }
```

The from1.c[Design] code is below here:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication_with_Main_Prg
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Program.Number.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The timer event will never get fired as you are using blocking code call  `Application.Run(new Form1());`

You should change your code to the following:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    aTimer.Elapsed += aTimer_Elapsed;
    aTimer.Interval = 1000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
    Application.Run(new Form1());  
}
```